# FPGA Atlys Spartan 6 output predefined image or string through HDMI

Tags: fpga, hdmi, spartan

I need help with displaying a short text on a hdmi display connected to the board (2 characters), I have already experimented with xapp495 but I still don't know how to do this.

I understand that it may be needed to save the characters as images in the memory or maybe in an attached ROM.

Could you instruct me how to achieve this, or maybe provide a premade source code that has this specific function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question has received no response so:

First: *"or maybe provide a premade source code"*
No, we do not provide source code to solve your problems. It against the rules and for a good reason.

Second: I had a quick look at xapp495. The very first diagram shows that the application needs a video stream: three 8-bit data streams (RGB) plus Hsync Vsync an VDE. That is a more or less standard format for video and **you** have to make that video stream.

Coming back to the first point: making a video stream requires a lot more code than can easily fit on a stackexchange page. So even if I wanted, I could not 'give' you that code as it is a small project by itself.
(It would take me about one or two days and that is with years of Verilog experience and a thorough knowledge of how an RGB video stream looks like).